# Can Install SSAS (Sql Analysis services) for Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ubuntu, ssas

Can Install SSAS (Sql Analysis services) for Ubuntu server 16.04.3 on EC2 AWS ?.

I have Ubuntu server on EC2 AWS, I want install SSAS (Sql Analysis services) ,
how to can install ?

Answer (score 0):

No, SSAS is not current available on Linux. Analysis Services is currently listed under [unsupported features and services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes) in the release notes. The notes also mention that:

> support of these features will be increasingly enabled over time