# Python library to connect to SSAS model in Linux environment

Tags: python-3.x, linux, azure, azure-functions, ssas

I had developed the script to refresh tables in SSAS model using python. It was working fine in my local, but I want to deploy the script in Azure Function.

In Azure Function, if we choose Python, only OS available in Linux. The python library (Pyadomd - https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/ ) I used to refresh the table does not work on Linux, it works only with Windows OS.

Kindly suggest some alternative python libraries to connect to SSAS model to perform operations like partition creation, partition deletion, partition & table refresh.

Comment: did you find a solution to this trying to do the same thing. i am trying to Use a python function app to refresh a data model.  ran into the same issue with  Pyadomd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Can Install SSAS (Sql Analysis services) for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383822/can-install-ssas-sql-analysis-services-for-ubuntu). SSAS is not available on linux although there exists some other methods. First you have to install `CData ODBC Driver` then install `pip install pyodbc`. The full article is here https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/ssas-odbc-python-linux.rst.

Comment: On Linux OS (in local), we can install the ```CData ODBC Driver``` as per your suggestion, but how can we achieve the same in ```Azure Functions```, running with ```Operating System - Linux```

Comment: @Beginner hmm yeah after looking into this you might want to try something like `Azure Analysis Services` more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518885/connect-to-azure-analysis-services-in-azure-function-in-runtime-version-3-1 . You can also try using an actual instance rather than Azure Functions I know it might cost more but it gives you more access to the OS because Azure functions are serverless.