# do you need to append path for pyadomd when deploying to an azure function app

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am creating an azure python function app (windows) and plan to use pyadomd to Query SSAS Tabular model based on a timer trigger. The documentation shows https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/ that `path.append('\\Program Files\\Microsoft.NET\\ADOMD.NET\\150')` is required before importing Pyadomd. Would this also work when deploying to azure? or is this just required locally.

Comment: I believe for Python you can only create Linux OS function app see [this](https://i.imgur.com/G5YpKF0.png)

Comment: @Ikhtesam Afrin is this for all python versions as well for example 3.9

Comment: Yes its for all the versions check [this](https://i.imgur.com/YD1OUyG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am creating an azure python function app (windows) and plan to use pyadomd to Query SSAS Tabular model based on a timer trigger.

You can only create a Python Function App for Linux operating system. It looks like Windows OS is not available If you will choose Runtime Stack as **Python**.

[image]

As per this [Doc](https://pypi.org/project/pyadomd/), **pyadomd** is only supported in Windows. So when you will run your function locally, it might work depending on your local machines OS but AFAIK, it will give you error post deploying to function app.

[image]

**References**-

[Python library to connect to SSAS model in Linux environment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77259227/python-library-to-connect-to-ssas-model-in-linux-environment).